# How to distribute static charges evenly on a finite plate?

Tags: electrostatics, charge

There are several ways to make charges on an object evenly distributed. For example, if the surface of the object is infinite or the object is a sphere. There is one more way which I am not sure if it is a good way: if the object is made out of an insulating material.

I would like to know if there are other ways to make the charges on a finite charged plate evenly distributed over the surface? Also, how efficient is the idea of using an insulating material?

Comment: Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A charged conducting material in the form of a sphere or an infinite plane can only be uniformly charged in the absence of external charges.
Any other shape of charged conducting material can be induced to be uniformly charged by the placing the right external charge density around it.
A conducting infinite cylinder is also uniformly charged (in the absence of external charges).
All these shapes share a common property: they lack corners - in a corner, the electrical field produced by cations is stronger, and the electrons can not order themselves spontaneously in a uniform manner.

In an insulating material, there is no problem since the electrons lack the mobility they have in a conducting material and can't redistribute themselves, so it can be uniformly charged regardless of it's shape or of external charge distribution.

Comment: Wouldn't chages on a cylinder accumulate on top or bottom since they are like corners?

Comment: @Starior You've got it - for a finite cylinder - That's why it has to be an infinite cylinder (as it is in my answer).

Comment: Oh okay sorry. I didn't see that. Thanks for your answer. Are there another ways other than these you mentioned in your answer?

Comment: @Starior I guess you're interested in another shape of metal which, with no external field, would have a uniform charge? (since I've mentioned that in all other cases, any shape would do). There are no more shapes that would fit the uniform curvature condition I have mentioned in my answer... in a 3d space, the maximum number of degrees of freedom one can use to describe a curvature on a surface is two: the sphere has two degrees. The next form would have one degree - that's the cylinder. And the final one has zero - a plane.

Comment: I mean with external charges. Is there any way to evenly distribute the charges on the object with external field?

Comment: @Starior Of course, In my answer I have mentioned that any conducting shape could have a uniform charge density given the right external distribution of charges. whenever you see too many electrons huddled together in one spot on the shape's surface, just put some negative charge nearby to make them flee, or a positive charge elsewhere to convince them to migrate closer to it in the hope of eternal happiness :)

Comment: If we can't change the external charge distribution I mean what if there is another charged object ,for example, under or top of the cylinder?

Comment: @Starior, Just one charged object would never be able to induce a uniform charge density on another object, unless it surrounds it completely (i.e. your metallic object is inside another charged shape) - in which case, we return to my comment above.

Comment: I am asking if there is one charged object near the object we want its charges to be evenly distributed, how can we manage to evenly distribute its charges? I know we can not perfectly do that but what method is the most useful one?

Comment: @Starior, as I've mentioned in a comment above - place the negatively charged object near a place where you want the charge density to be more positive, or the positively charged object where you want the charge density to be more negative... The distance between the objects would determine how much you affect the charge distribution, and how localised the effect is (in case the inducing object is smaller than the metallic shape).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16783/discussion-between-starior-and-mr-worshipme).

Comment: I thought of an another method that could work. Since the charges on a sphere is evenly distributed no matter what the sphere is made out of, if the finite plate could be made out of very small spheres(I'm talking about nanotechnology) the charges on the plate should be evenly distributed. Am I right?

Comment: It would not be perfectly evenly distributed, since the spheres that are not in the middle would be polarized because they would see less charge on one side and more on the other. But if the spheres are very small compared to your measurement's distance, it would indeed look pretty homogeneous. Since the spheres do not touch and hold on to their charge, you could look at the insulating material as consisting of such very small spheres.